# Unable to read the json files which is located in any folder different from assets folder in Angular 2/4

Tags: json, angular

Trying to read a json file with http.get in Angular 4 project using the following script.

```
http.get('../jsonmock/data.json')
.subscribe(res  =>  this.data = res.json() );
```

If I try to read the json file from assets folder it runs successfully but from any other folder I got the following error on console

http.get('../jsonmock/data.json')
.subscribe(res  =>  this.data = res.json() );

Response {_body: "↵↵↵↵↵↵", status: 404, ok: false, statusText: "Not Found", headers: Headers, …}
headers
:
Headers {_headers: Map(8), _normalizedNames: Map(8)}
ok
:
false
status
:
404
statusText
:
"Not Found"
type
:
2
url
:
"http://localhost:4200/jsonmock/data.json"
_body
:
"↵↵↵↵Error↵↵↵

```
Cannot GET /jsonmock/data.json
```

↵↵↵"
**proto**
:
Body
constructor
:
ƒ Response(responseOptions)
arguments
:
(...)
caller
:
(...)
length
:
1
name
:
"Response"
prototype
:
Body {constructor: ƒ, toString: ƒ}
**proto**
:
ƒ Body()
[[FunctionLocation]]
:
http.es5.js:900
[[Scopes]]
:
Scopes[3]
toString
:
ƒ ()

Comment: Assuming you are using the CLI, once you build or serve the app, webpack is bundling your app together and deploying it in a different directory (distribution directory). This means that after bundling, your app only has access to whatever got bundled or what got copied into the assets folder. I would do what DeborahK suggested and load the json into your assets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the Angular CLI ... it will only look for assets in the folders you tell it to in the .angular-cli.json file.

In the "apps" node there is a node called "assets":

```
  "assets": [
    "assets",
    "api",
    "favicon.ico"
  ],
```

By default, only the assets and the favicon are here. If you want it to look in other locations for your .json file, you need to specify those locations here, as I did with the `api` folder.